# Method overview in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, is it possible to show an overview of all methods (and maybe class variables) of the currently opened file? For instance, in Eclipse, the default settings comprise an overview as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried "View | File Structure"?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have found the option in at "Navigate | File Structure" or CTRL+F12.